# How to change tile title with new Live Tile templates in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal app?

Tags: c#, live-tile, win-universal-app

Right now, I'm generating custom tiles for my app. But I'd like to change the title of the tile as well, being dynamically (e.g., I can show the current location).

In WP8 you were able to set the `Title` and the `BackTitle`, but these parameters seems to be missing in Universal Apps.

Any idea on how to do this? I think it's only possible to set `Branding` to `BadgeIcon` or app Title? I'd like to set the (Front)Title to a string, and back title to nothing.

```
/// RENDERING THE TILES
string WideFrontTile = await RenderWideFront(WeatherData);
string MediumFrontTile = await RenderMediumFront(WeatherData);
string WideBackTile = await RenderWideBack(WeatherData);
string MediumBackTile = await RenderMediumBack(WeatherData);

// FRONT TILES
ITileWide310x150Image WideFrontContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileWide310x150Image();
WideFrontContent.Image.Src = WideFrontTile;
ITileSquare150x150Image MediumFrontContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquare150x150Image();
MediumFrontContent.Image.Src = MediumFrontTile;
WideFrontContent.Square150x150Content = MediumFrontContent;

// BACK TILES
ITileWide310x150Image WideBackContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileWide310x150Image();
WideBackContent.Image.Src = WideBackTile;
ITileSquare150x150Image MediumBackContent = TileContentFactory.CreateTileSquare150x150Image();
MediumBackContent.Image.Src = MediumBackTile;
WideBackContent.Square150x150Content = MediumBackContent;


// Clear all tiles, push new tiles
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(WideBackContent.CreateNotification());
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(WideFrontContent.CreateNotification());
```

Kind regards,
Niels

Comment: I ended up rendering the titles into the image, while turning Branding to Branding.None.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the attribute "branding":

```
    var TileMgr = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
    TileMgr.Clear();
    var tileTemplate = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150Image);

    // Quitamos el nombre de la app.
    XmlElement tmp = tileTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("visual")[0] as XmlElement;
    tmp.SetAttribute("branding", "none");
    var notification = new TileNotification(tileTemplate);
    TileMgr.Update(notification);
```